# Install font for emacs 24.x

Tags: emacs, truetype, emacs24

I've installed emacs 24.3, and I would like to use a specific font (Meslo LG M DZ), but when I launch emacs, I have the message "Font `Meslo LG M DZ' is not defined". What is strange, is that when I downgrade emacs version from 24 to 23, using the same configuration file, I can use this font without any problem...

Here is how I declare Meslo in the configuration file :

```
(setq default-frame-alist
  '(
    (width . 80)
    (tool-bar-lines . 0)
    => (font . "Meslo LG M DZ") <=
    (vertical-scroll-bars . nil)
    ))
(unless (fboundp 'prog-mode) (defalias 'prog-mode 'fundamental-mode))
...
```

How can I solve this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It was just a matter of compilation option...
I didn't use "--without-xft", but I needed to explicitly put "--with-xft".

Answer (score 0):

You could try setting the font manually using the 
    Options->Set default font 
menu, and then clicking 
    Options->Save Options, which will write the setting automatically to your .emacs file. You could then use that snippet henceforth.

Comment: Yes, I've already tried that, but here again, there is a difference. Under emacs23, I have a little box to select the font, but under emacs24, I juste have a menu, where my font doesn't even appear.

Comment: Do you think about anyting else? Maybe I'm missing something at compilation time?

Comment: Unfortunately I can't think of anything. It's probably a regression introduced in 24. You could try sending a bug report to the emacs dev team.

Comment: OK, thank you for your help then. I will report this to emacs team.